# Hosting Django and Path to Project Directory

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am using a digital ocean virtual server to host a django web app.  when you create the droplet, it creates a default app in the directory `/home/django/django_project/django`.  However seeing as this isn't the app I want to host, I put my application files into the directory `/home/myproject/myapp` and updated the gunicorn and nginx configs to point there.  However once updating the urls for this app, I am trying to see it online and noticed that the 404 looked like this: [image]

which states that the URLconf is defined in django_project.urls which I had since deleted out of that `'home/django` directory.  I have reloaded and restarted gunicorn and nginx in an attempt to get django to realize that the project django_project doesn’t exist any more, but no luck.  Has anyone run into this before or have any suggestions as to what I should try next?

Comment: You may share gunicorn conf adn urls.py

Comment: Double check your nginx and gunicorn conf files to make sure the paths are correct.

Comment: what is theconf adn urls.py?  Where can I find it?  Also I have check the two configs and they are correct.